# String escaping

Tags: c#, string

I want find and replace a substring in a string in C#.
The substring I want to find looks like this:
`],\"`
and the substring i want to replace looks like this `],\"Name`

This is what i tried so far:

```
string find = @"],\""";
string replace = @"],\""Name";
string newjson = jsonstring.Replace( find, replace );
```

Comment: So why do you think it didn't work?

Comment: Please be specific. What is the input string? What is the result? Please post a _complete_, concise code example that reproduces the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: no Visual Studio compiles. No syntax error so far

Comment: Ok, so why did you ask a question? You don't say what went wrong with what you tried.

Comment: Debugger show me like this "],\\\"Name"

Comment: Can you tell us what is the result you see in `newjson`? Also, please edit your question so we could see the contents of `jsonstring`.

Comment: I don't want tripple \ !!!

Comment: The debugger escapes strings with the non `@` syntax. There is nothing wrong with your code. Try writing the string to a file or with `Debug.WriteLine(newjson)` and you will see there is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment

> Debugger show me like this `"],\\\"Name"`

That is the correct output, the debugger is showing you the escaped version of your string. the `\\` turns in to a single `\` and the `\"` turns in to a `"` once the escaping has been applied.

If you click the magnifying glass in the box in your debugger it will open a new window with the escaping applied.

[image]

Comment: @PeterDuniho actually I had 3, stack overflow escaped my text! had to wrap it with backticks to get the 3rd to show up.

Comment: Always a good idea to double-check the rendered output when posting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors when doing what you did?

Otherwise try without using a literal "@"

so something like this:

`string find = "],\\\"";`

`string replace = "],\\\"Name";`

`string newjson = jsonstring.Replace(find, replace);`

Sometime double quotes and string literals still give me issues so I do it that way without using the literal. Hope that helps.